# Keycloak returns 'Invalid parameter: redirect_uri'

Tags: docker, oauth-2.0, keycloak

**[Edit-1] Add scope in oauth2 configuration, add grafana service, remove `oauth-keycloak-signin`. The configurations is referred from [this link](https://maif.github.io/izanami/manual/tutorials/oauth2.html)**

**[UPDATE]** I am able to log in at Keycloak page but it couldn't route me to the Grafana service. Looked at the OAuth2 logs, something weird, the access token that generated by Keycloak was validated of Github, not for Keycloak :))) -> **This was caused by missing oauth validate_url config.**

**`Solution`**:

```
- 'traefik.http.middlewares.oauth-keycloak.forwardauth.address=http://oauth-keycloak:4185/oauth2/auth'
```

Log of OAuth2 Proxy

```
paddy_oauth-keycloak.1.nd9v50gfv9kc@staging    | 123.28.110.207 - 411d7575-fb97-42ca-87ed-d57cad683b31 - - [2021/09/30 02:04:53] grafana.my-domain.com GET - "/oauth2/start?rd=https%3A%2F%2Fgrafana.my-domain.com%2F" HTTP/1.1 "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36" 302 419 0.000
paddy_oauth-keycloak.1.nd9v50gfv9kc@staging    | [2021/09/30 02:05:00] [internal_util.go:74] token validation request failed: status 400 - {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Token not provided"}
paddy_oauth-keycloak.1.nd9v50gfv9kc@staging    | [2021/09/30 02:05:00] [internal_util.go:69] 400 GET https://keycloak.my-domain.com/auth/realms/staging/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo?access_token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJYa1NjbzduRjlaTUpiWDRXVU5mTlhJS2FwOG9ZMHZ1THVZZU1SUk9EQ1J3In0.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... {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Token not provided"}
paddy_oauth-keycloak.1.nd9v50gfv9kc@staging    | 123.28.110.207 - 39bea317-002b-4366-858c-01aa6f6901b6 - dathuynh@my-domain.com [2021/09/30 02:05:00] [AuthSuccess] Authenticated via OAuth2: Session{email:dathuynh@my-domain.com user: PreferredUsername: token:true groups:[/pader]}
```

I am setting up keycloak and oauth2 for authentication in my system. The system is running in docker swarm mode and using traefik reverse-proxy. I followed this guide to set up the oauth2 container: https://oauth2-proxy.github.io/oauth2-proxy/docs/configuration/oauth_provider/#keycloak-auth-provider

I created a new client in the 'development' realm, with the Valid Redirect URL is `https://oauth-keycloak.my-domain.com/oauth2/callback` (it is the Oauth URL), used traefik forward auth to route the request to the Keycloak if it is unauthenticated.

I got `Invalid parameter: redirect_uri` for 2 case:

- I access Grafana and the request was routed to Keycloak
- I try to access this link in the OAuth config `https://oauth-keycloak.my-domain.com/auth/realms/development/protocol/openid-connect/auth`.

I have searched and try some suggestions but they did not work for me. Hope you guys can help. I have really appreciated it.

Here is my docker swarm configuration:

```
  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:15.0.2
    deploy:
      labels:
        - "traefik.enable=true"
        - "traefik.http.routers.keycloak.rule=Host(`keycloak.my-domain.com`)"
        - "traefik.http.routers.keycloak.entrypoints=websecure"
        - "traefik.http.routers.keycloak.tls=true"
        - "traefik.http.routers.keycloak.tls.certresolver=leresolver"
        # Set up service
        - "traefik.http.routers.keycloak.service=keycloak-svc"
        - "traefik.http.services.keycloak-svc.loadbalancer.server.port=8080"
    environment:
      - "DB_VENDOR=POSTGRES"
      - "DB_ADDR=postgis"
      - "DB_DATABASE=${POSTGRES_DB}"
      - "DB_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}"
      - "DB_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}"
      - "KEYCLOAK_USER="
      - "KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD="
      - "PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true"
      - "KEYCLOAK_LOGLEVEL=DEBUG" # DEBUG, ERROR, INFO

  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 256M
      labels:
        - "traefik.enable=true"
        - "traefik.http.routers.grafana.rule=Host(`grafana.my-domain.com`)"
        - "traefik.http.routers.grafana.entrypoints=websecure"
        - "traefik.http.routers.grafana.tls=true"
        - "traefik.http.routers.grafana.tls.certresolver=leresolver"
        # Basic HTTP authentication
        - "traefik.http.routers.grafana.middlewares=oauth-keycloak"
        # Set up service
        - "traefik.http.services.grafana-svc.loadbalancer.server.port=3000"
        - "traefik.http.routers.grafana.service=grafana-svc"
    environment:
      - GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_USER=my-username
      - GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_PASSWORD=my-pasword
      - GF_USERS_ALLOW_SIGN_UP=true
    volumes:
      - "/home/app/grafana:/var/lib/grafana"

  oauth-keycloak:
    image: quay.io/oauth2-proxy/oauth2-proxy
    deploy:
      labels:
        - "traefik.enable=true"
        - "traefik.http.routers.oauth-keycloak.rule=Host(`oauth-keycloak.my-domain.com`) || PathPrefix(`/oauth2`)"
        - "traefik.http.routers.oauth-keycloak.entrypoints=websecure"
        - "traefik.http.routers.oauth-keycloak.tls=true"
        - "traefik.http.routers.oauth-keycloak.tls.certresolver=leresolver"
        # Set up service
        - "traefik.http.routers.oauth-keycloak.service=oauth-keycloak-svc"
        - "traefik.http.services.oauth-keycloak-svc.loadbalancer.server.port=4185"
        # Set up middlewares
        - 'traefik.http.middlewares.oauth-keycloak.forwardauth.address=http://oauth-keycloak:4185'
        - 'traefik.http.middlewares.oauth-keycloak.forwardauth.trustForwardHeader=true'
        - 'traefik.http.middlewares.oauth-keycloak.forwardauth.authResponseHeaders=X-Forwarded-User'
        # - "traefik.http.middlewares.oauth-keycloak-signin.errors.service=oauth-keycloak-svc"
        # - "traefik.http.middlewares.oauth-keycloak-signin.errors.status=401-403"
        # - "traefik.http.middlewares.oauth-keycloak-signin.errors.query=/oauth2/sign_in"
    environment:
      OAUTH2_PROXY_CLIENT_ID: 'development'
      OAUTH2_PROXY_CLIENT_SECRET: '' 
      OAUTH2_PROXY_PROVIDER: 'keycloak'
      OAUTH2_PROXY_SCOPE: 'profile email address phone'
      OAUTH2_PROXY_LOGIN_URL: 'https://keycloak.my-domain.com/auth/realms/development/protocol/openid-connect/auth'
      OAUTH2_PROXY_REDEEM_URL: 'https://keycloak.my-domain.com/auth/realms/development/protocol/openid-connect/token'
      OAUTH2_PROXY_PROFILE_URL: 'https://keycloak.my-domain.com/auth/realms/development/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo'
      OAUTH2_PROXY_VALIDATE_URL: 'https://keycloak.my-domain.com/auth/realms/development/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo'
      
      OAUTH2_PROXY_COOKIE_DOMAINS: 'my-domain.com'
      OAUTH2_PROXY_HTTP_ADDRESS: '0.0.0.0:4185'
      OAUTH2_PROXY_COOKIE_REFRESH: '1h'
      OAUTH2_PROXY_COOKIE_SECURE: 'false'
      OAUTH2_PROXY_COOKIE_SECRET: '0Y18nYVtNLzKQroYQpi0jw=='
      OAUTH2_PROXY_EMAIL_DOMAINS: 'my-domain.com'
      OAUTH2_PROXY_REVERSE_PROXY: 'true'
      OAUTH2_PROXY_WHITELIST_DOMAINS: 'my-domain.com'
      OAUTH2_PROXY_SHOW_DEBUG_ON_ERROR: 'true'
```

Comment: Please provide full URL of the page, where you see `Invalid parameter: redirect_uri`.

Comment: Hi @JanGaraj, I have updated the url page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You configured a valid redirect URI for `https://oauth-keycloak.my-domain.com/oauth2/callback` as you said. In case of accessing grafana your redirect uri should be `https://grafana.my-domain.com/oauth2/callback` instead. You will need to add this to the list of valid redirect URIs as well.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I added the Grafana URL then the web page returns 403 with `Login Failed: The upstream identity provider returned an error: invalid_scope`. Am I missing any scope configurations in the Keycloak `Client Scopes`?

Comment: It looks like Grafana is initiating the login with `scope=api`. You will need to add a client scope `api` to Keycloak and add it to your client (`authentication`?) as either optional or default. You may also want to consider to have a separate client for Grafana in Keycloak.

Comment: @tandathuynh148 Configure Grafana properly https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/auth/generic-oauth/ It depens how used client has configured scopes in the Keycloak, but usually it should be `scope = openid profile email`

Comment: Grafana is just an example. My system has many services like pgadmin, dashboard, and other build services so that I need a single sign-on and manage the users like who can access a particular service and who is restricted. Really thanks for your finding, I'll try to figure out what causes 403 error

Comment: Hi @sventorben, Could you help look at the new edit? By adding the scope in oauth configuration, I was able to access the login page and login with user account but successfully login, the service routed me to `grafana.my-domain.com` with `404 page not found`. I don't really know what happened with it.

Comment: Under which URL is your Grafana located?

Comment: Hi @sventorben, I attached the OAuth logs in the post. Keycloak generated an access token but outh2 can not validate that it from keycloak, OAuth thought that it was Github token

Comment: I think you misconfigured it. It is reaching out to https://keycloak.org/... which is hosted on github. I think you need to replace that config with the URL to your actual Keycloak instance.

Comment: just found that I miss the _PROXY_ in oauth2 environment variables. It should be `OAUTH2_PROXY_VALIDATE_URL`

Comment: But there are till some errors with the tocken `{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Token not provided"}`

Comment: Your proxy passes the access token as a query parameter `?access_token=eyJhb...` to Keycloak's userprofile endpoint. I don't think this is supported. the token must be present in the `Authorization` header

Comment: Hi @sventorben, finally it works. I have missed the forawrdAuth address for OAuth. Thank you for your nice suggestions