# keycloak's access token is validated as github access token by oauth2

Tags: docker, github, oauth-2.0, oauth, keycloak

I have some microservices that need to be protected with authentication. So that I used OAuth2 + Keycloak. You can see the detailed configurations from this post ([Keycloak returns 'Invalid parameter: redirect_uri'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69286211/keycloak-returns-invalid-parameter-redirect-uri)).

After successfully login in, the keycloak generates an access token that is routed to the OAUth2 service for validating. Somehow, the OAuth2 thinks the access token was from github, not from the keycloak. You can see the logs:

```
123.28.110.207 - 78368701-f2b3-48c2-8f57-3a77a6b385f0 - - [2021/09/28 03:20:52] grafana.my-domain.com GET - "/oauth2/start?rd=https%3A%2F%2Fgrafana.my-domain.com%2F" HTTP/1.1 "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36" 302 419 0.000 [2021/09/28 03:21:06] [internal_util.go:64] GET https://keycloak.org/api/v3/user?access_token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJvNXViN... [2021/09/28 03:21:06] [internal_util.go:65] token validation request failed: error performing request: Get "https://keycloak.org/api/v3/user?access_token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJvNXViNgmU66CrcaFozOg": x509: certificate is valid for *.github.com, github.com, not keycloak.org
123.28.110.207 - a4f32698-44f4-463d-831e-93c292fb91ea - dathuynh@my-domain.com [2021/09/28 03:21:06] [AuthSuccess] Authenticated via OAuth2: Session{email:dathuynh@my-domain.com user: PreferredUsername: token:true}
123.28.110.207 - a4f32698-44f4-463d-831e-93c292fb91ea - - [2021/09/28 03:21:05] grafana.my-domain.com GET - "/oauth2/callback?state=rVOsXkFxqswYCI8LhKTCOAUUjP76i8k3ltnqJcoxEDU%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fgrafana.my-domain.com%2F&session_state=36f8da18-6477-4a72-a7d2-10aadc5a0679&code=b9bbeb85-45bf-4fb5-ad31-cd6a59fc955f.36f8da18-6477-4a72-a7d2-10aadc5a0679.9f5b720c-0be6-44f0-946f-62e34ca0e5ec" HTTP/1.1 "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36" 302 63 0.955
123.28.110.207 - a25fe783-0e8f-48de-8040-80e77c98d35b - dathuynh@my-domain.com [2021/09/28 03:21:06] grafana.my-domain.com GET
- "/" HTTP/1.1 "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36" 404 19 0.000
123.28.110.207 - c5eeb805-c532-401b-aed4-d462b8b26d11 - dathuynh@my-domain.com [2021/09/28 03:21:07] grafana.my-domain.com GET
- "/" HTTP/1.1 "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36" 404 19 0.000
```

I might miss something in Keycloak configuration but I don't really know. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

**[UPDATE]** I have found the issue, the traefik ForwardAuth middleware has wrong confurations address. You can see the error log in OAuth2 but is not crucial. YOu can find the solution in my previous post if you're interested.

Answer (score 1):

That is a problem with the TLS server certificate configured at `keycloak.org`. But moreover, it seems that this is a wrongly configured validation URL in your software unless you actually control or trust `keycloak.org` and your tokens are issued by a server running on that domain.

Comment: I miss a validate url configuration in oauth so causes this error. But after I fix it, the oauth still can not validate the URL, it shows 404 error `{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Token not provided"}`